# Java Regex, remove leading spaces of each line

Tags: java, regex

Want to use Java String.replaceAll(regex, "") to remove all leading spaces of each line in a multi-line text string. if possible remove all carriage-returns as well. What the "regex" should be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use regex replacement in Java:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?m)^\\s+|\\s+$", "");
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?m)`: Enable `MULTILINE` mode so that `^` and `$` are matched in every line.
- `^\\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces at line start
- `|`: OR
- `\\s+$`: Match 1+ whitespaces before line end